# Trying to connect to an API for IGDB

Tags: ruby, api, twitch

I've been trying to connect to an API for a Project in school. I'm currently using Ruby. I'm trying to connect to the API for IGDB and display video games and I just cannot. I've been getting nothing but errors. I have the keys with me, but I just cannot connect to API or even display anything. Any help to be able to help me connect would be greatly appreciated.

```
require 'net/https'
POST https://api.igdb.com/v4/games
Client_ID = 'Client ID'
Authorization = 'Bearer + Access Token'
http = Net::HTTP.new('api.igdb.com/v4',443)
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(URI('https://api.igdb.com/v4/games'), {'Client_ID' => 'Client ID', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer access_token'})
request.body = 'fields age_ratings,aggregated_rating,aggregated_rating_count,alternative_names,artworks,bundles,category,checksum,collection,cover,created_at,dlcs,expansions,external_games,first_release_date,follows,franchise,franchises,game_engines,game_modes,genres,hypes,involved_companies,keywords,multiplayer_modes,name,parent_game,platforms,player_perspectives,rating,rating_count,release_dates,screenshots,similar_games,slug,standalone_expansions,status,storyline,summary,tags,themes,total_rating,total_rating_count,updated_at,url,version_parent,version_title,videos,websites;'
puts http.request(request).body
```

Errors:

```
(With POST https://api.igdb.com/v4/games)
C:\Users\Saad>Ruby Test2.rb
Test2.rb:2: unknown regexp options - ap
POST https://api.igdb.com/v4/games

(W/O the POST line)
C:\Users\Saad>Ruby test2.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        9: from test2.rb:8:in `<main>'
        8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:1483:in `request'
        7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:932:in `start'
        6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:943:in `do_start'
        5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:958:in `connect'
        4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/timeout.rb:105:in `timeout'
        3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/timeout.rb:95:in `block in timeout'
        2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `block in connect'
        1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `open'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `initialize': getaddrinfo: No such host is known.  (SocketError)
        9: from test2.rb:8:in `<main>'
        8: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:1483:in `request'
        7: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:932:in `start'
        6: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:943:in `do_start'
        5: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:958:in `connect'
        4: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/timeout.rb:105:in `timeout'
        3: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/timeout.rb:95:in `block in timeout'
        2: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `block in connect'
        1: from C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `open'
C:/Ruby27-x64/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/http.rb:960:in `initialize': Failed to open TCP connection to api.igdb.com/v4:443 (getaddrinfo: No such host is known. ) (SocketError)
```

Comment: What errors you are receiving might be beneficial to the post. Most of us have likely never used this specific API but we do understand ruby and its errors for the most part.

Comment: Added the errors, thanks!

Comment: Remove the '/v4' portion from this line `http = Net::HTTP.new('api.igdb.com/v4',443)` and try again

Comment: I got the code part from here : https://api-docs.igdb.com/?ruby#game Also, removing the v4 gave me this error: {"message":"Unauthorized"}, probably because the it's the v4 of the API.

Comment: That's not an error that is a response so the code is working. You are putting your bearer token in right? E.g. `'Bearer access_token'` is being sent as `'Bearer ABC12345DFT'` or whatever your access token is

Comment: Yeah! Huh, so it is attempting to connect. So, I put, Bearer + My Access Token in the Authorization slot you see above and my results are what I showed to you.

Comment: `{"message": "Unauthorized"}` is a JSON response from the API so it seems like the issue is with the Header that authorizes access e.g client id and bearer token. Seems like the API is free maybe I will sign up so I can test properly

Answer (score 0):

Try using Wrapper provided by IGDB

Comment: This could be a really helpful if you could provide a direct link to the Wrapper you are mentioning.  And even better if you show an example with the Wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Someone asked Dhruv Shah which wrapper you could use.
The [igdb documentation](https://api-docs.igdb.com/) recommends [this wrapper](https://github.com/StefanGreffenius/ruby-apicalypse) for ruby.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33998675)